# Cannot fix "list index out of range"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a simple code in python to find the first missing positive integer. My algorithm is to create an array full of zeros with the size of maximum positive integer in the input array+1 (for example if the maximum number is 7, the size of 0's array would be 8). Then I trace the input array and whenever I find a positive number I change the index value+1 in the second array to 1. This is my code:

```
def minPositive(a):
   max_a = max(a)
   b = [0]*(max_a+1) # This is the second array initialized to zero
   for i in range(len(a)):
      if a[i] > 0:
          b[a[i]+1]= 1
   for j in range(len(b)):
      if j != 0:
          if b[j] == 0:
             return j
```

But when I code this I face "List index out of range". I traced my program several times but I cannot find the error.

Answer (score 0):

Python indexes from `0`, so a list of length `n` has no `n`th element. Likewise, a list with `n+1` elements has no `n+1`th element.

One option is for every positive value in `a` (rather than the value plus 1), the index corresponding to that value in `b` will be set to `1`. You could rewrite your function like this (simplified a bit):

```
def minPositive(a):
    b = [1 if n in a and n > 0 else 0 for n in range(max(a) + 1)]
    return b
```

Or you could just make your list `b` one element longer.